# The use of Interfaces

Tags: java, interface

From a **theoretical** point of view, what are interfaces good for?

I know that they allow us to implement multiple inheritance; but are they widely used for something else?

Comment: Primarily interfaces used as Loose Coupling Endpoints. Please Do readd about it.

Comment: They are more of a *design* choice. And please don't say that they allow us to implement *multiple inheritance*. *Java language doesn't support multiple inheritance*. They define an *unbreakable contract* which the *implementing* class should adhere to.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6916916/the-purpose-of-interfaces-in-java-language

Answer (score 3):

Interfaces help us to **define abstraction** for what some object **is** and how it should behave, while classes help us to **implement** that abstraction.

Answer (score 0):

An interface is a specifies what the object can do.

An abstract class specifies what an object is.

Comment: An interface specifies the *basic things that an instance of a class can do*. *An abstract class specifies what an object is.* - I don't get this line.

Comment: The interface is more like a blueprint for a building, when you implement the interface you fill in the bricks.

Comment: You can fill in the bricks.. paint your walls... place your windows.. and a lot of other things which the blueprint might not *have*.:P

Answer (score 0):

Interfaces allow you to define or classify similar types of behaviour across classes that are otherwise completely unrelated. You can do something similar with inheritance, but the classes are not loosely coupled.

See [this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/384067/110933)